# transforming data returned from firebase

Tags: angularjs, typescript

**What I'm trying to do:** receive data from fire base, and display some values from that data to the screen.

**How I've gone about doing it:** I have created an Angular SPA and the data I return from Firebase is as follows:
[Returned Data from Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll9IF.png)

**Error I'm receiving:**

I then use an *NgFor loop in the html portion of the component as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-group" *ngFor = "let guardian of guardians">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ guardian.firstname }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

I have looked for solutions to this and the common answer is to transform the received data into an array.  I have attempted to do that with the following:

```
    for (const guardian in data) {array.push(guardian);}
```

However, the array I receive back is missing all of my values.  It comes back in this form:

```
["-L3n95t-rxA4-bOgc8fz", "-L3nF0h5EEKtwAiZv0Q7",
 "-L3oWoBmoXK3-5XBkx9i", "-L3oWxEhAcUGQX2P4yES", "-L41_cK3KD6DMduhG3P3", 
"-L4CbTtNqGuVyT3hzY-R", "-L4CfKsBxfQxSKd2PR4s", "-L4EDFkbsWMrT61fLjhD"]
```

This allows me to use my *NgFor statement, but this data is useless to me now.  Any knowledge on how to transform this data?

After three days of banging my head against this one any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: can you post what the `guardians` object looks like?

Comment: Yes, when logged to the console this is what I get. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll9IF.png

Comment: `for (const guardian in data) {array.push(data[guardian]);}`

Comment: Thank you so much!  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The data in that array is actually each key within the guardians object. Now what you want to do is utilize those keys. Lets assume you gave your key array a value such as `this.guardianKeys = array`

Then you can iterate through the keys and access the original guardians objects like so:

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="list-group" *ngFor = "let key of guardianKeys">
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ guardians[key].City }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ guardians[key].Phone }}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">{{ guardians[key].State }}</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution solved my problem.

```
for (const guardian in data) {array.push(data[guardian]);}
```

by pushing this into an empty array I was then able to iterate through the array with *NgFor.